# Shutil.move doesn't move files

Tags: python

I am trying to move PDF files from one folder to another using shutil.move. After I execute the script, python doesn't see them anymore, while they are still visible in Windows explorer. If I run the script again, python tells me there are no files. I have to run reverse script in order for python to see them. I use 64-bit Python v3.6.4 on Windows 10.
[Command prompt with counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSmbs.jpg)

```
import os, sys
import shutil
from os.path import join

Filez=0
PDFZ=0
filovi = os.listdir("C:/Users/Mirko1/pdfannots-master/NoGo")
for file in filovi:
    Filez +=1
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        newdr=join('C:\\', 'Users','Mirko1','pdfannots-master','NoGo', file)
        olddr=join('C:\\', 'Users','Mirko1','pdfannots-master', file)
        PDFZ +=1
        shutil.move(newdr, olddr)

print(Filez)
print(PDFZ)
```

Comment: `'C:\\'` needs to be either `r'C:\\'` or `'C:\\\\'`. Try again from there.

Comment: Also: You might want to use `file.lower().endswith('.pdf')`.

Comment: As a note for the future -- a much clearer [mcve] would, say, create a file named `dir1/a.txt` and move it to `dir2`; all the code here beyond the call to `Shutil.move()` is chances for unrelated things to go wrong, making it less certain that (as the title claims) it's actually the `move()` call at fault.

Comment: (actually, a proper [mcve] would create *both* `dir1` and `dir2`, as well as `dir1/a.txt` -- thus being complete enough that all someone needs to do to see the problem is copy-and-paste the code, without having to create any files ahead-of-time).

Comment: (I do think it's likely that the extensions are actually `.PDF` instead of `.pdf`, as @dhke suggests -- but providing a standalone reproducer would avoid the need for that kind of guesswork).

Comment: I updated the script and it still behaves as previously. I run it once, it tells me that there are 15 files, 6 of which are PDFs. I check the folder and all files are still in. I run the script again. Now it tells me that I have 9 files and 0 are PDFs. I check folders and everything is the same, no files were moved. No I run the opposite script and it tells me that it moved 6 pdf files back.

Comment: I also tried shutil.copy() and shutil.copy2() and it doesn't work. Nothing gets copied

Comment: Found where the problem was - Comodo Internet Security was isolating the scripts. As soon as I unblocked them, everything worked properly.